# LeftSideMenu without Storyboard swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I need your help.
I'm developing a app without Storyboard (using xib), in my project I have two views controllers.
In the main view (after a login) I need to put a button on top of the view to open a left side menu. 
This is how I call the MainView on LoginViewController

```
    @IBAction func logar(){
    let vc = MainViewController(nibName: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

I imported SWRevealViewController, and this is my MainViewController:

```
import UIKit
```

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //hide BackButton
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    //image
    var image = UIImage(named: "menuBtn")
    image = image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    //lefBarButonItem
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(MainViewController.openMenu))

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;

}


func openMenu(){
    let frontViewController = LeftMenuTableViewController()
    let rearViewController  = MainViewController()


    //create instance of swRevealVC based on front and rear VC
    let swRevealVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearViewController, frontViewController: frontViewController);
    swRevealVC.toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationType.EaseOut;
    swRevealVC.toggleAnimationDuration = 0.30;

    //set swRevealVC as rootVC of windows
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = swRevealVC

}
```

}

When I press the button the LeftMenu occupy all the view, not like a partial view.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!